# Lefschetz number and Euler characteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Allan Hatchers Algebraic topology (https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) p.179 it was stated that if $f:X \to X$ for X a finite CW complex is homotopic to the identity then the Lefschetz number $\tau(X)$ is the Euler characteristic of X. Now I'm struggling with the question why this holds.
When f is homotopic to the identity then the induced map on the homology is equal to the identity (homotopy invariance of singular homology groups), i.e. $$f_* =\text{id}_*:H_n(X) \to H_n(X)$$ and thus the Lefschetz number of f is given by
$$\tau(f) = \sum\limits_n (-1)^n \text{tr}(\text{id}_*:H_n(X) \to H_n(X)) = \sum\limits_n (-1)^n n = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ...$$
because the trace of the identity map is given by $\text{tr}(id)=\sum\limits_i^n 1 = n$. But the Euler characteristic is $$\chi(X) = \sum\limits_n (-1)^n\ \text{rank}(H_n(X)).$$
This confuses me a lot at the moment. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trace of the map $id_* : H_n(X) \to H_n(X)$ is not equal to $n$. It is equal to $\beta_n = \text{rank}(H_n(X))$, because the identity map on $H_n(X)$ is represented by a $\beta_n \times \beta_n$ identity matrix. So the Lefschitz number of the identity is $\sum (-1)^n \beta_n$ which equals the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much, I really stucked on this!